# Движение формы за панель

Tags: c#, winforms

Нашел в интернете решение задачи, перемещения формы за панель. 
Прикрутил к себе, но работать не хочет.

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.Capture = false;
    Message m = Message.Create(base.Handle, 161, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
    this.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: что-то на C# смахивает. Это не javascript, поэтому и не работает

Comment: Да, да вопрос по C#, Метку JS по ошибке написал.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так

```
  private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Capture = false;
        Message m = Message.Create(Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
        WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

 private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: увы не работает

Comment: Только что проверил, все работает, и при передвижении за форму, и за панель. Вот проект: http://rghost.ru/51080759

Answer (score 0):

Для того что-бы корректно работало и можно было перечислить несколько объектов
нужно вешать данный код не на событие MouseDown а на MouseMove

Cобытие можно указать вручную в Конструкторе, ну или принудительно инициализировать при загрузке формы Form1()
c помощью Имя_объекта.MouseMove += MouseMoveForm;
Это уже кому как удобнее, я лично не люблю тонну кода, и мне проще через Конструктор
он сам указывает все события в Form1.Designer.cs вместо того что-бы самому всё прописывать в Form1.cs

Так же добавил ещё одну полезную функцию Развернуть и Свернуть в окно при двойном клике мышки

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseMove += MouseMoveForm;
        //label1.MouseMove += MouseMoveForm;
        //button1.MouseMove += MouseMoveForm;
        //pictureBox1.MouseMove += MouseMoveForm;
    }
    private void MouseMoveForm(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Развернуть и Свернуть в окно при двойном клике мышки
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 2)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
        base.Capture = false; // <- Основной объект "Окно формы"
        // указываем все объекты за которые можно перетаскивать форму
        // label1.Capture = false;
        // button1.Capture = false;
        // pictureBox1.Capture = false;
        Message m = Message.Create(base.Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
        this.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Иногда при создание проекта нужно сделать окно формы полностью со своим дизайном
и при этом нужно что-бы его можно было растягивать как обычную форму с параметрами FormBorderStyle = Sizable
так же добавил изменение цвета границы окна с толщиной в 1 пиксель как в Visual Studio
когда окно находиться в состояние Normal рамка светиться синим цветом
когда окно находиться в состояние Maximized рамка светиться красным цветом

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 121, 203), 1))
            {
                    Rectangle borderRect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Top, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, borderRect);
            }
        }
        else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0), 1))
            {
                Rectangle borderRect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Top, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, borderRect);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal || WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE = 10;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x0084/*NCHITTEST*/ :
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if ((int)m.Result == 0x01/*HTCLIENT*/)
                {
                    Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                    Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);
                    if (clientPoint.Y <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)13/*HTTOPLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)12/*HTTOP*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)14/*HTTOPRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)10/*HTLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)2/*HTCAPTION*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)11/*HTRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)16/*HTBOTTOMLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)15/*HTBOTTOM*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)17/*HTBOTTOMRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                }
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: А про что, вообще, речь?